# cannot open file using dockerfile golang

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have a file on the root of my project, and I am opening it like this:

```
    file, err := os.Open("file.csv")
```

When I make `go run main.go` it works. When I use the dockerfile to run the app it doesn't work:

> open fiile.csv: no such file or directory

My dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
RUN mkdir /build 
ADD . /build/
WORKDIR /build 
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main .
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /build/main /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["./main"]
```

I am not used to dockerfiles so any improv is welcome too!

Comment: Which directory is the csv located, if /build/ then you need to ensure that you copy that directory, not just main? Also, ensure there isn' t any interference with a .dockerignore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the line `COPY --from=builder /build/main /app/` you only copy the executable. You do not copy the app directory. Replace that line with `COPY --from=builder /build /app/`

Below I have included an example of how I would write this Dockerfile. Here are some key changes.

- Define `WORKDIR` before `COPY` instructions so you do not have write directory names twice. This is helpful because if you want to change your app directory, you only need to change it once (and that means smaller chance of bugs).
- Use `COPY` instead of `ADD`. The [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) indicates that `COPY` is preferred.
- You do not have to use `RUN mkdir /build` before using a `WORKDIR` or `COPY`. Those last two instructions will make the directory if it does not exist already.

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main .
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build .
CMD ["./main"]
```